# Refresh Token In Asp.net Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, token, access-token, refresh-token

My angular application is connected with an asp.net web API project. Token expiry timeout is 20 mins. Below is my startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888

            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions option = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(option);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my token is not getting refreshed on every call and it is automatically getting expired after 20 mins. How can I refresh a token on every API call?

Answer (score 0):

Pls add refresh token provider in the config method -

```
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            //The Path For generating the Toekn
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            //Setting the Token Expired Time (30 minutes)
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            //MyAuthorizationServerProvider class will validate the user credentials
            Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            //For creating the refresh token and regenerate the new access token
            RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
        };
        
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
}
```